# .NET Core reloadOnChange settings in container

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have a simple .net core console app that just prints in screen a string that reads from the settings

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("Settings/appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    var configuration = builder.Build();

    while (true)
    {
        var greeting = configuration.GetSection("MySettings").GetSection("Greeting").Value;
        Console.WriteLine(greeting);
    }        
}
```

When I run it locally the reloadOnChange works fine and I get the change in the string seamlessly.

So now I was trying to run it within a containe, for which I added a simple dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/DynamicConfig.dll"]
```

And tried to test that if I mounted the local appsettings file I would get that reloadOnChange behaviour, initially I tried to mount just the file but after reading some potential issues (although I think they could be overcome) decided to move it under that Settings folder. Yet, I don't get it to change

The command that I use to run it is

> docker run -it --rm -v /${PWD}/Settings:/app/Settings myimage

It has a slight different syntax for the usage in a Windows machine (and have even tried to map to /app/out/Settings with no luck neither)

Would love to hear something around the reasons this doesn't "work"

Thanks

Comment: Does adding a `ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true` in the `Dockerfile` help?

Comment: Adding it didn't seem to help

Comment: @OmairMajid I take my comment back, I can't understand why but the console (git bash on conemu) keeps outputting the original string, it's just a loop writing to console, but if I open a new console and attach to the running container when adding that env variable it honours the change in that second console